# How to create table with vertical/column header in JavaFX

Tags: javafx

Is there a way to create tableview with vertical headings ? I don't see any option in javafx to do this.

Comment: not supported .. as you know by not seeing any option in the api doc :)

Comment: seeing the answer, I noticed that I misunderstood the question :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the graphic to a `Label` which is rotated, and set the text to an empty string.

```
private void makeColumnHeader(TableColumn<?,?> column) {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText(column.getText());
    column.setText("");
    label.setRotate(90);
    column.setGraphic(label);
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private void makeColumnHeader(TableColumn<?,?> column) {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.setText(column.getText());
        column.setText("");
        label.setRotate(90);
        column.setGraphic(label);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        TableView<Item> table = new TableView<>();
        TableColumn<Item, Number> idColumn = new TableColumn<>("Id");
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleIntegerProperty(data.getValue().id()));
        TableColumn<Item, String> itemColumn = new TableColumn<>("Item");
        itemColumn.setCellValueFactory(data -> new SimpleStringProperty(data.getValue().name()));

        makeColumnHeader(idColumn);
        makeColumnHeader(itemColumn);

        table.getColumns().add(idColumn);
        table.getColumns().add(itemColumn);

        for (int i = 1 ; i <= 20; i++) table.getItems().add(new Item(i, "Item "+i));

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(table);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static record Item(int id, String name){}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

[image]

Note that setting the column's text to an empty string can have undesirable side effects. For example, the [`tableMenuButton`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/19/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html#tableMenuButtonVisibleProperty) relies on the text in the table columns to display the menu items. Add `table.setTableMenuButtonVisible(true);` to the code above to see the problem.

A slightly more robust solution is to bind the text of the label in the graphic to the text in the column, and then use CSS to hide the default text:

```
private void makeColumnHeader(TableColumn<?,?> column) {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.textProperty().bind(column.textProperty());
    label.setRotate(90);
    column.setGraphic(label);
}
```

and in an external style sheet:

```
.table-column > .label {
    -fx-content-display: graphic-only;
}
```

Comment: For me, it would be easier to read the rotated labels if they were rotated left (-90), rather than right (90).  Perhaps that is just a personal thing.

Answer (score 1):

I had to adapt the solution from @James_D to properly size the label by applying a minWidth and wrapping it in a Group: (Tested with openjfx19)

```
    private void makeColumnHeader(TableColumn<?, ?> column, String text)    {
    Label label = new Label();
    label.setText(text);
    label.setRotate(-90);
    label.setMinWidth(80);
    column.setGraphic(new Group(label));
    column.getStyleClass().add("rotated");
}
```